# Eternal loading time with Update statement in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, sqldatasource

I have this code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="UpdateFullNameSQL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UserQueries %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UserQueries.ProviderName %>" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE USERS SET FIRSTNAME = :changefirstname, LASTNAME = :changelastname WHERE (USERNAME = :currentusername)">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ChangeFirstNameBox" Name="changefirstname" PropertyName="Text" Type="Empty" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ChangeLastNameBox" Name="changelastname" PropertyName="Text" Type="Empty" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="UsernameBox" Name="currentusername" PropertyName="Text" Type="Empty" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

After I hit the button, it starts to load, but loads forever and nothing happens.

Any suggestions? (I'm using an Oracle database, so changing the : sign to @ just shows another missing expression exception.)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried running a normal update query from the C# code?
you can try that and see if it is doing the same.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really know how to do that, because I guess I would need to set up the connection for the Oracle database in the code, but I am using Oracle Developer Tools right now and that makes the connection, I don't need to do it myself.

Comment: you can just create a Oracle connection object and pass in the connection string and then use the command object to execute the update query. its pretty simple.